# Is it possible to apply validation attribute that was made with IModelValidator to the model class?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We can create custom validation attributes using IModelValidator. Example:

```
public class LanguageValidator : Attribute, IModelValidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I know that this attribute can be applied to the model class properties.

Tell me please, is it possible to apply it to the model class?

Comment: How about using `ValidationAttribute` and `IClientModelValidator` to validate the model? Are you using MVC 3/4/5 or Core MVC?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I'm using asp.net core. I want to get attribute validation class that will have opportunity to validate all model properties and return  all errors associated with model class at the same time. The closest improvement to solve this problem is to implement  IValidatableObject. But, I do not like the idea that I will need to implement IValidatableObject in the model class. I know that IModelValidator can be used to create custom validation attributes that can be applied to class properties. But I'm not sure if this attribute can be used on the model class level.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you are looking for… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1 … implementing IValidatableObject can be used to implement class-level validation as seen here.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Thank you for the given approach. I know about it. But, I do not like the idea that I will need to implement IValidatableObject in the model class. I know that IModelValidator can be used to create custom validation attributes that can be applied to class properties. But I'm not sure if this attribute can be used on the model class level.

Comment: You want to create on class containing the validation logic for a model class and apply is using an attribute to your model class. Correct? Afaik that's not possible, but I not sure.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Yes, you are absolutely right.